# Грааль: святой или священный?

Tags: грамотная-речь

На вопрос меня натолкнул нижепреведенный забавный ценник.
А вопрос такой: Грааль все-таки святой или священный?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ценник  смотрится  как  "шутка  юмора".  Но  в  остальном  вопрос  серьёзный.  Такие  пары  слов  (сходных  по  смыслу,  но  различных  по  значимым  оттенкам  этого  смысла)  называются  паронимами.  Есть  соответствующие  словари.  Но  в  доступных  мне  словарях  я  этой  пары  не  нашёл.  Поэтому  обратился  к  толковому  словарю  Ожегова.  Вот  статья  на  слово  "священый":                                  СВЯЩЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -ён и -ёнен, -ённа. 1. В религии: обладающий святостью, божественный; соответствующий религиозному идеалу. С. сан. 2. Относящийся к религиозному культу. С. обряд. Священная утварь. 3. Чрезвычайно почётный и исключительный по важности, святой (в 3 знач.) (высок.). Священная обязанность. С. долг. 4. Исполненный благоговения. С. трепет. С. восторг. * Священное писание— религиозные книги. Христианское Священное писание (признанные Православной Церковью как канонические 27 книг Нового Завета и 38 книг Ветхого Завета). Иудейское Священное писание (Ветхий Завет).   Священное  писание  ислама (Коран). II сущ. священность, -и, ж. (к 1, 3 и 4 знач.).                                                   Согласно  пункту  второму,  Грааль,  безусловно - "священный".  Так  он  и  именуется  в  литературе.                                                                      У  слова  "святой"  несколько  иной  набор  значений.  Привожу  статью  из  того  же  словаря:  "СВЯТОЙ, -ая, -бе; свят, свята, свято. 1. В религиозных представлениях: обладающий божественной благодатью. С. старец. С. источник. Святая вода (освящённая). 2. Проникнутый высокими чувствами, возвышенный, идеальный (высок.). Святая любовь к Родине. 3. Истинный, величественный и исключительный по важности (высок.). Святое дело. Святая обязанность. 4. святой, -бго, м. В христианстве и нек-рых других религиях: человек, посвятивший свою жизнь церкви и религии, а после смерти признанный образцом праведной жизни и носителем чудодейственной силы. Культ святых. Причислить к лику святых. * Святая истина — о чём-н. бесспорном, неоспоримом. Святая святых (высок.) — нечто самое дорогое, сокровенное [первонач. место в Иерусалимском храме, в к-ром хранились заповеди Моисея]. Святые места — места, связанные с представлениями о божественных деяниях, чудесах, жизни святых угодников. Паломничество к святым местам. Хоть святых выноси (разг.) — о невообразимом шуме, беспорядке. Свято место пусто не бывает (разг. ирон.) — всегда найдётся тот, кто займёт какое-н. освободившееся место,должность. Свят-свят-свят! (устар. разг.)— заклинание, ограждающее себя от че-го-н. опасного, страшного. Как Бог свят (устар. разг.) — божба. II ж. святая, -бй (к 4 знач.). \сущ. святость, -и, ж. (к 1, 2 и 3 знач.).

Answer (score 1):

Святой http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Святой_Грааль . Но также можно сказать и священный. По ссылке есть информация о фильме "Монти Пайтон и Священный Грааль (1975)" где "юмористически обыгрывается известная легенда о короле Артуре, его соратниках, их скитаниях в поиске Чаши **святого Грааля**".